# How to run a filter when calling git status?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

Following [Git clean and smudge filters don't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646172/git-clean-and-smudge-filters-dont-do-anything/60569968#60569968) If I run `strace -qqqqqqq -fe execve -e signal=none git status` it only runs `git status`. Does this mean that there is no way to run filters before showing the modified files in the working-tree? I would like to omit those jupyter notebooks that appear as modified because of the `execution_count property` of the cells were changed, but not the actual code. I already have the script that would output a clean version of the notebook, but I would like to know if it is possible to run like a `git diff` to the files to decide whether to show or not after I do a `git status`. Thanks

Comment: `git status` works hard to *avoid* using the code it contains that implements `git diff` if at all possible; but if it does need to run a diff, `git status` already has that code in it, so it does not actually run a separate `git diff` command. Whether and when this runs a clean filter is another question, but if `git status` can tell that the work-tree file matches the index copy, it won't.